# how can we make sure that all activity is written to the job log file from the script and the PL/SQL program

Tags: oracle, shell, logging, plsql

we have a shell script (programname.shl) that will execute a PL/SQL program (programname). The shell script opens a log file (programname.log) and then starts appending line to it using the echo statement. When the PL/SQL program is executed withing the script, the program opens the same log file in append mode. After the shell script executes we see the lines written from the shell script before the program was executed and the lines from the PL/SQL program that were written to the log. However, none of the lines echoed after the program was executed appear in the log file. What would cause this?

Comment: TL;DR, _line buffering_ ?

Comment: Can you post your shell script? Also, the before/after log?

Comment: Does the PL/SQL program use `UTL_FILE`?  Does it call `FCLOSE` at the end?  My wild guess is that PL/SQL locks the file, writes all it's lines at once, and doesn't release the file until the connection/script ends.